# File download with spring mvc

Tags: file, spring-mvc, download, glassfish-3

I'm trying to give user ability to download a file which is created after database backup.

this is my controller where I try to generate link for that file and than in Javascript I just make  tag with the generated link. after clicking the link chrome says "not allowed to load content from local resource: file:///...". can anyone tell me how to allow to load this resource? I'd prefer not to change the directory which is now /tmp

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/backup-entire-database", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Responce backupEntireDatabase(@RequestBody Map<String, String> databasePasswordMap) throws MalformedURLException {
        String databaseUserPassword = databasePasswordMap.get("password");
        ShellScript databaseBackupScript = new ShellScript();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy*MM*dd_HH*mm*ss");
        Date now = new Date();
        String currentTime = sdfDate.format(now);
        try {
            databaseBackupScript.exec("database-backup", databaseUserPassword , "databaseBackup_"+currentTime, "", "");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DatabaseBackupController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return new Responce(0, ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ShellScriptExecutionExeption ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DatabaseBackupController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return new Responce(0, ex.getMessage());
        }
        File backupFile=new File("/tmp/PATH_TO_FILE/databaseBackup_"+currentTime);
        return new Responce(0, backupFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
    }
```

Comment: You need a controller which streams the file to the client. Simply returning the URL of the file to the client isn't going to work (the file is created on the server not the client). file:// indicates a local resource not a server resource.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479563/download-xls-file-via-post-to-spring-mvc?answertab=active#tab-top